# Memcache : Two Seperate Memcache's instances in sync for a single application

Tags: memcached

I am working on a heavy traffic web site , where there will be GB's of data written per minute into our Memcache .
So we have decided to use two separate instances of Memcache for the application .

So right now as per the set up , there are two Memcache  instances for  a single application .

Now my question is , once we recive a value inside the application ,  which writes/sets to both the Memcache instances , assume that  if a key is read one of the instance of 
Memcache - 1 , i need to delete the same key on  the other instance of memcahce  also at the same time , so taht they will be in sync with each other .

As per the code point of view once  a value is read from Memcache , i am deleting that key .

**Let me put things on a clear note . This is a Streaming application , where one part of application writes data to both the instances of the Memcache , and there is an other side of the application which reads from either one of the instance of Memcache , so if Data is read from one instance needs to delete from another instance at the same time .**

Is there any way or any plugin to accomplish this ??

Comment: So, your `write` writes to both the instances and `read` reads from any one?

Comment: yes ,correct,it  reads from any one , and once it is read it must be deleted from the second instance also .

Comment: so, 1. why are you deleting instead of leaving the data in MCD?, 2. Once you `read` the data from one. Just go ahead and `purge` the key in all instances one by one. What is the problem?

Comment: This is a streaming application , i will be receiving the data continuously for the same key from a 3rd party application .

Comment: ok. Then just keep setting `key` in both instances, it will overwrite the data for the key. No need of explicit delete and then `set`. BTW, please mind the network traffic connecting to MCD servers if it's real fast data. It _may_ add unwanted delay if you `connect -> get -> connect -> delete 1 -> connect -> delete 2 -> connect -> set 1 -> connect -> set 2` vs `connect -> set 1 -> connect -> set 2`.

Comment: There are two instances of Memcache running (so there is no link between them) and inside the  application , it  gets access to both instances of Memcahe  and  writes to both instances , my question is how the key will be deleted automatically ??

Comment: Let me put things on a clear note .

This is a Streaming application , where one part of application writes data  to both the instances of the Memcache , and there is an other side of the application which reads from either one of the instance of Memcache , so if Data is read from one instance needs to delete from another instance at the same time .